# How to call remote ejb on pramati server by spring on tomcat

Tags: spring, ejb

Hi I have to write remote client for ejb. EJb is running on pramiti server and i want to write client in spring.

Answer (score 0):

You can access remote Ejbs with the SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean. Also, check the source/javadocs for information: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/4.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/ejb/access/SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean.java#SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean

```
<bean id="ApplicationServiceBean" class="org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="test/ApplicationServiceBean/remote" />
    <property name="businessInterface" value="your.ApplicationService" />
    <property name="jndiEnvironment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://zaphod:42</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```